# Sending array json body with arrays inside of it (Alamofire, Swift, iOS)

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

i want to send json body to my middleware. at first, it works well (note that the "tema" & "emailGroup" wasn't an array). but after some changes on my backend, i have to send this type of json

```
[{
    "ID": "",
    "Name": "Artikel BU CE - Visit HoB Topic",
    "ChannelType": 0,
    "PublishDate": "2018-09-21T01:00:00Z",
    "Headline": null,
    "Content": null,
    "EmailSubject": null,
    "EmailUrl": null,
    "Mention": null,
    "PostLink": null,
    "ChannelActivityMobileId": null,
    "HashTag": null,
    "Tema": [
        {
            "Value": 6
        }
    ],
    "EmailGroup": [
        {
            "ID": "2c53ea1f-6ebe-e811-a977-000d3aa00fc2",
            "Name": "TV Broadcast",
            "List_EmailListModels": null
        }
    ],
    "ApprovalStatus": 0,
    "ApprovalNote": null,
    "EmployeeId": null,
    "EmployeeLevel": 0
}]
```

here's my code

```
let parameters = [["ID" : "", SerializationKeys.channelMobileId : channel.mobileId, SerializationKeys.name : activity.activityName, "ApprovalStatus" : channel.channelStatus, SerializationKeys.channelType : channel.channelType, SerializationKeys.publish_date : channel.publishDate, SerializationKeys.content : channel.content,  SerializationKeys.emailSubject : channel.emailSubject, SerializationKeys.emailURL : channel.emailURL, SerializationKeys.hashtag : channel.hastag, SerializationKeys.mention : channel.mention, SerializationKeys.note : channel.note, SerializationKeys.postLink : channel.postLink, SerializationKeys.tema : [tema]] as [[String : Any]]
```

where tema is

```
var tema = [String : Int]()
```

i got an error that says

> [Any] is not convertible to '[[String : Any]]'; did you mean to use as! to force downcast?

and after i change "as" to "as!", it says

> Excpected ";" separator

where the semicolon should put near "SerializationKeys.tema : [tema]". Please kindly help me. Thanks

**EDIT**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mistakenly added **]** near

```
, SerializationKeys.postLink : channel.postLink],
```

You may want this

```
let parameters:[[String:Any]] = [["ID" : "",
                   SerializationKeys.channelMobileId : channel.mobileId,
                   SerializationKeys.name : activity.activityName,
                  "ApprovalStatus" : channel.channelStatus,
                   SerializationKeys.channelType : channel.channelType,
                   SerializationKeys.publish_date : channel.publishDate, 
                   SerializationKeys.content : channel.content,  
                   SerializationKeys.emailSubject : channel.emailSubject,
                   SerializationKeys.emailURL : channel.emailURL,
                   SerializationKeys.hashtag : channel.hastag, 
                   SerializationKeys.mention : channel.mention, 
                   SerializationKeys.note : channel.note, 
                   SerializationKeys.postLink : channel.postLink,
                   SerializationKeys.tema : [tema]
               ]]
```

**Note:** I heighly recommend using `Codable` with `struct` models for your case

Comment: hello, thanks for spotting my mistake. anyway, i still got an error "Excpected ";" separator". can you please provide me the code?

Comment: Can you screenshoot the error when appear and attach it temporarily in question then remove it

Comment: look at my updated question. the other word says "Variable usde within its own initial value"

Comment: Before as there is 3 **]]]** not 2 **]]**